# mongodb aggregate a new field from (sub array of objects) of array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have those objects

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
  { item: 'notebook', status: 'A', size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: 'in' }, instock: [{ qty: 5 }] },
  { item: 'paper', status: 'D', size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: 'in' }, instock: [{ warehouse: [{ status: 'A' }], qty: 60 }] },
  { item: 'planner', status: 'D', size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: 'cm' }, instock: [{ warehouse: [{ status: 'B' }], qty: 40 }] },
  {
    item: 'postcard',
    status: 'A',
    size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: 'cm' },
    instock: [
      {
        warehouse: [
          { status: 'A', createdAt: new Date('01.01.2020') },
          { status: 'C', createdAt: new Date('01.01.2022') },
          { status: 'B', createdAt: new Date('01.01.2021') }
        ],
        qty: 1
      },
      {
        warehouse: [
          { status: 'D', createdAt: new Date('01.01.2024') },
          { status: 'F', createdAt: new Date('01.01.2026') },
          { status: 'E', createdAt: new Date('01.01.2025') }
        ],
        qty: 12
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

I want to map array so I have new items like:

```
[
  ...
  , {
    instock: [
      {
        warehouseStatus: 'C',
        qty: 1
      },
      {
        warehouseStatus: 'F',
        qty: 12
      }
    ]
  }
  , ...
]
```

Basically inStock elements would have a new field called warehouseStatus which is the status of the newest object from instock.warehouse, sorted by createdAt.

I tried:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      instock: {
        warehouseStatus: [
          {
            $sortArray: {
              input: '$instock.warehouse',
              sortBy: { createdAt: 1 }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But it returns nonsense.

There is mongo console here, if you want to test: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Please help I consumed my last brain cell today.

mongodb aggregation that will map my data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $set: {
  instock: {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$instock",
      "as": "i",
      "in": {
        qty: "$$i.qty",
        warehouse: "$$i.warehouse",
        warehauseStatus: {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$$i.warehouse",
            {
              "$indexOfArray": [
                "$$i.warehouse.createdAt",
                {
                  "$max": "$$i.warehouse.createdAt"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
 {
$set: {
  instock: {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$instock",
      "as": "i",
      "in": {
        qty: "$$i.qty",
        warehouse: "$$i.warehouse",
        warehauseStatus: "$$i.warehauseStatus.status"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Using indexOfArray set the warehouseStatus to max element based on createdAt field
2. Set the status value to the warehauseStatus field.

[Playground:](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zvK4gYpFlE0)